# how to fix this GREP statement

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I'm trying to select just the `x`

```
舌ぽう (舌鋒x) ぜっぽう (sharp) tongue
じょう舌 (饒x舌) じょうぜつ garrulity, loquacity
```

Its always in parentheses. So I want to LookBehind for a left parenthesis then zero or more characters, and LookAhead for zero or more character followed by a parenthesis.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't: `(?<=\(.?)x(?=.?\))`

This one will select all the text between the parentheses, but I only want the `x`: `(?<=\().?x.?(?=\))`

I also tried this (not sure if you can have two lookbehinds...but it didn't work:

`(?<=\()(?<=.?)x(?=.?)(?=\))`

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: one question, are those brackets in your input text always paired?

Comment: Just a small point: "zero or more characters" is reprecented by `*` not by `?`

Comment: Whoah!  I've never seen anyone try to grep Chinese!

Answer (score 1):

Grep doesn't support variable length lookarounds. You could do something like:

```bsh
# grep for x inside parenthesis 
$ grep -Po '\(.*x.*?\)' file
(舌鋒x)
(饒x舌)

# pipe to grep again for just the x 
$ grep -Po '\(.*x.*?\)' file | grep -o x
x
x
```

Comment: Hi @sudo_O, I'm doing this in Indesign's Find/ChangeGrep tool, so I can't pipe. can I nest it in a single statement somehow?

Comment: (surprised I found something GREP can't do. Thought it could do anything!)

Comment: I don't think it's possible then *(I have zero experience with Indesign?)*

Answer (score 1):

from OP's comment, I assume that the brackets are always paired.

The problem here is the look-behind needs a fixed length, which in this question we cannot know.

But if the `(..)` are always paired, we could just check the `closing )`. This should give what you want:

```
grep -Po "x(?=[^)]*\))" file
```

let's test it a bit:

```
kent$  echo "舌ぽう (舌鋒x) ぜっぽう (sharp) tongue
じょう舌 (饒x舌) じょうぜつ garrulity, loquacity"|grep -Po "x(?=[^)]*\))"
x
x
```

another test, I added `y` in brackets, and assume we want that `y` too:

```
kent$  echo "舌ぽう (舌y鋒x) ぜっぽう (sharp) tongue
じょう舌 (y饒x舌) じょうぜつ garrulity, loquacity"|grep -Po "[yx](?=[^)]*\))"
y
x
y
x
```

**EDIT**

```
grep -Po "x(?=[^)(]*\))" file
```

this should be ok:

```
kent$  echo "じょうx舌 (饒x舌) じょうぜつ garrxlity, loquacity"|grep -Po "x(?=[^)(]*\))"
x
```

Comment: but it also finds x's which are outside the parentheses

Comment: `じょうx舌 (饒x舌) じょうぜつ garrxlity, loquacity` seems if would find all three `x` in that string, not just the x in the parentheses

Comment: @MaxHodges see EDIT. it should be ok for your new example. also the old command doesn't find all **three** `x`, but the first two instances. since it could be nested parentheses case. but now I fixed it.

Comment: x(?=[^)(]*\))

x Literal character 
(?= Lookahead Group
 [ Error: Unmatched Open Square Bracket
 ^ Start of Paragraph, Story, Footnote, or Cell
) End Lookahead Group
( Begin Group #1
 ] Error: Unmatched End Group Character ']'
 * Error: Unexpected special character!
 \) Literal closing parenthesis
) End Group #1

Answer (score 0):

can't do it all in one, but can do it with multiple statements, one for each specific case:

```
(?<=\(.)x(?=.\))

(?<=\(.{2})x(?=.{1}\))

(?<=\(.{2})x(?=.{2}\))

(?<=\(.{1})x(?=.{2}\))

(?<=\(.{3})x(?=.{1}\))
```

etc

Comment: it is possible to do it in one short if the `(,)` are always paired.

Comment: good to know, but would be better if you can demonstrate! Post a solution?